# Replace dot by comma after title and authors' names in biblatex

Tags: bibliographies

I have issues with my references and would like to replace the dot < . > which is between the authors' names and the title by a comma < , >. I would also like to replace the dot between the title and the journal name by a comma when printing the references. Here is my current code:

In `bibliography.bib`

```
@article{hiller2001developmental,
  title={Developmental regulation of transcription by a tissue-specific TAF homolog},
  author={Hiller, Mark A and Lin, Ting-Yi and Wood, Cricket and Fuller, Margaret T},
  journal={Genes \& development},
  volume={15},
  number={8},
  pages={1021--1030},
  year={2001},
  publisher={Cold Spring Harbor Lab}
}
```

In
`main.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Section}
\cite{hiller2001developmental}

\bibliographystyle{plain} % We choose the "plain" reference style
\bibliography{bibliography} % Entries are in the bibliography.bib file

\end{document}
```

The reference will be:
[image: bib]

I am trying to get a comma after `Fuller` as well as after `homolog`.

```
[13] Mark A Hiller, Ting-Yi Lin, Cricket Wood, and Margaret T Fuller, De-
     velopmental regulation of transcription by a tissue-specific taf homolog,
     Genes & development, 15(8):1021–1030, 2001
```

Comment: Since you are using standard BibTeX (`\bibliographystyle{plain}`) I have removed the `biblatex` tag to avoid confusion. (`biblatex` is not compatible with BibTeX styles and modifications to `biblatex` styles are very different from modifications of BibTeX styles.)

Comment: OK, thank you @moewe. But the most important thing for me is to have the bibliography in the above structure, starting with the reference number, e.g. `[13]`, having the full stops replaced by commas, and making the references have the structure we have in `bibliography.bib`. Therefore, I would also be happy with a solution that uses `biblatex`.

Comment: Getting the exact same output with `biblatex` (just with a comma instead of a period) is going to be painful with `biblatex`. But getting a structurally similar output is not (https://gist.github.com/moewew/fe6a265d7c615862766f284a91743d85).

Comment: Thank you @moewe. Can we have something like `[1],[2]` instead of `[1,2]` when citing multiple references, e.g. `\ autocite{hiller2001developmental, sigfridsson}` ?

Comment: Use `style=numeric-comp,` instead of `style=numeric,`.